# Alternate value of "FeedUri" for contacts entry

Tags: c#, google-contacts-api

I am trying to create a contact on Google Apps.
I am using Admin credential to create contact in other users in same domain.

Problem i am facing is when i use:

```
Uri feedUri  = new Uri(ContactsQuery.CreateContactsUri("default"));
ContactEntry createdEntry = (ContactEntry)service.Insert(feedUri, ContactEntry[0]);
```

It is adding contact in Admin account but i a want to put contact in other user's account.

How can i do that?

**I tried with :**

Uri feedUri  = new Uri(ContactsQuery.CreateContactsUri("user@domain.com"));

But is giving exception: "Execution of request failed".

**I am using Google Apps API version 2 for .NET.**

**Creating service as :**

```
ContactsService obj_ContactService = new ContactsService("");
obj_ContactService.setUserCredentials(userEmail, password); // Admin's Email and Password
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
Uri feedUri = new Uri(http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/youruser%40gmail.com/full");
ContactEntry createdEntry = (ContactEntry)service.Insert(feedUri , ContactEntry[0]);
```

Comment: No it's not working.again showing same error : "Execution of request failed".

Comment: the problem lies in : obj_ContactService.setUserCredentials(userEmail, password);   you should use domain-wide authentication, not the admin's personal client login

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RequestSettings settings = new RequestSettings("yourAppName", appDomainName, DomainConsumerSecret, userId, appDomainName);   //the userId is the pure id without "@yourdomain.com" 
ContactsRequest  contactsRequest = new ContactsRequest(settings);
Uri feedUri = new Uri(ContactsQuery.CreateContactsUri("default"));
Contact createdEntry = contactsRequest.Insert<Contact>(feedUri, contact);
```

the above code should work.